# Using [DebuggerHidden] prevents code coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, attributes, code-coverage

I have a helper class which one of the methods has the [DebuggerHidden] attribute so it does not show in the call stack.

```
/// <summary>
/// Encapsulates guard-clause logic for conditions to allow a neat and tidy single line call
/// </summary>
public static partial class Guard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if the specified condition is true. If it is 
    /// a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown with the 
    /// argument name
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    /// Guard.ArgumentOutOfRange((collection.Count == 1), "arg1");
    /// </example>
    /// <param name="condition">if set to <c>true</c> the ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown.</param>
    /// <param name="argumentName">Name of the argument.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"></exception>
    [DebuggerHidden]    //Does not appear at all in the call stack
    public static void ArgumentOutOfRange(Boolean condition, [InvokerParameterName] string argumentName)
    {
        Throw<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>.If(condition, argumentName);
    }
}
```

This is great except as it does what I need.... except for when I am checking for test code coverage as including this attribute seems to exclude the method from the test results. Is there a way around this as I would like to see this method has good coverage without having to keep adding and removing the attribute when I test for coverage?

I am using framework 4.0 which I understand has a dedicated attribute to stop code coverage so why does [DebuggerHidden] still affect this?

Comment: According to that article [DebuggerHidden] should have no affect but it IS having an effect and my code is excluded from the results. I want it to be INCLUDED in the code coverage results but not in an EXCEPTION CALL STACK.

Comment: This is [by design](http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2008/11/10/hiding-generated-code-from-code-analysis-metrics-and-test-coverage.aspx).  Realistically, if you don't yet have enough confidence that a method is adequately tested then you should not hide it from the debugger and exception diagnostics.  Consider [DebuggerStepThrough] until you get there.